# Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, suggested-edits, character-limit

I tried to update a jQuery code block that was missing a curly brace. The code is incorrect, but I cannot edit it since changes under 6 characters are not allowed (at least at my level of rep?).

I understand why you don't want to allow minor copy-editing, and I agree that's fine for textual descriptions and regular writing, but 1 character can make a big difference in code.

Comment: Where was this, SO? I can make edits as minor as inserting a single character here on MSO.

Comment: Yes it was StackOverflow.

Comment: @Popular There is a character limit if you are doing edits with less than 2000 reputation. And, apparently, it's 6. At 2000 and higher, there is no such requirement.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93977/editing-an-so-answer-with-6-characters-to-correct-code-syntax

Comment: Incidentally, what *is* the reason for 6 characters - simply to reduce the burden on moderators?

Comment: I've seen atrocious code listings with inconsistent indentation or bracing styles. Cleaning those up can go a long way towards getting someone to help answer the question. Its rare that there isn't more that can't be fixed, but it is the case sometimes and prevents helping improve a question. I guess 2k is the answer but in the mean time the question (and my eyes) suffer.

Comment: @mindless.panda: I thought whitespace edits don't count toward the quota

Comment: Jeff's answer is dead-on here: either earn the privilege to edit as you please, or work within the restrictions placed on untrusted editors.

Answer (score 11):

Allowing edits of less than 6 characters in code blocks might not be a bad idea for answers, but
 **it may be problematic for questions**.

Don't take me the wrong way, I'm not a big fan of the 6 character rule, as I've seen editors do some strange and irritating things to meet the requirement, (I saw someone edit in the word "link" after a link, just so they could remove a comma).

I've seen a few questions where the reason the OP was asking about their code ended up being as simple as a missing curly brace, comma, semicolon, or what have you.

In these cases a suggestion to add the missing character would be a great comment, or possibly an acceptable answer.
<sup>Notice that I said an acceptable answer not a great answer.</sup>

If these corrections are edited into the question then it could leave a non-sense question asking whats wrong with perfectly working code.

Answer (score 7):

Was the post otherwise so perfect that *absolutely nothing* in it could be improved?

I'm sympathetic when the issue is a single character error in code, but I also believe deeply in the idea of encouraging people to go beyond the minimum level of effort.

So your options are

- earn 2k rep and character twiddle away
- with less than 2k rep -- while you are there, improve some other aspect of the post to reach the 6 character threshold

Comment: Take the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163459/reading-integers-from-binary-file-in-python

I really want to change "struck" to "struct". I don't know enough Python to change anything else. I understand wanting to nudge users into more substantive changes. But this hard, rigid, inflexible, uncompromising rule strikes me as wrong. Any other change I would make to that answer would just be pointless fiddling to get around the rule.

Comment: I've taken a liking to the review process and code listings in particular can sometimes really improve a question. Sometimes I work a few minutes to improve the indentation/bracing/layout but have to abandon the edit because I don't know enough about the rest of the subject matter to try and improve.

Comment: "Was the post otherwise so perfect that absolutely nothing in it could be improved?"  Yes.  Do you understand that this rule *discourages* people from fixing errors, making the sites' content less trustworthy in the long run?

Comment: @endo it encourages people to earn 2k rep if they want the privilege of making trivial bit-twiddling changes. Peer review costs time.

Comment: @JefAtwood: It discourages people from fixing factual errors in answers (which will in turn cause problems for hundreds or thousands of readers).  Sometimes it actually *prevents* them from fixing errors without resorting to hackish workarounds.  I'm a peer reviewer, and it would be very stupid to reject a 1-character edit that fixed a bug in example code or 3-letter edit that reversed the meaning of a mistyped sentence, just because the editor hadn't met some prerequisite of busywork.

Comment: RT Answer by @JeffAtwood: yes, that is exactly what I do. After editing the error which is bugging me, I take out my thesaurus and go word-hunting...

Comment: I think the rule (and the answer by Jeff Atwood is not very helpful. Indeed, you may either discourage willing helpers - or create an extra burden to the reviewers, because people just might start changing random things to circumvent the 6 character limit. Prettifying / correcting code is helpful for many other readers. But if that's undesired, I can keep myself aloof from helping in those cases.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a critical edit be constrained by the need to dig up a minor improvement?  This answer has the tenor of logically convincing fortitude, but seems more like a practice in the power of rhetorical debate for its own sake, rather than being worthwhile.

Comment: "..while you are there, improve some other aspect of the post to reach the 6 character threshold". In my limited experience this tends to be frowned upon.

Answer (score 2):

This question is constantly repeated, which I think itself is indication of a conveyance issue with the way the error is phrased.

What do we think about changing the text of this error to **"Edits must be at least 6 characters for users under 2000 reputation; is there something else to improve in this post?"**

This is so it's clear this isn't a universal restriction, but one limited to new users?

Comment: Asking a new feature request to make it clear that users with editing privileges aren't subject to the 6-character limit is a better way to actually get it implemented. It's something I'd support, and after searching, I couldn't find a duplicate. (There was [one case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327443/the-dreaded-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) where a user was actually unaware of this.)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I've created a new feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328525/change-phrasing-of-under-6-characters-minimum-message-to-prevent-confusion-and), feel free to make it more clear, it's a little "wall of text"-ish.