# Allow smaller edits for everyone

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction)

Basically, in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/256759/adding-default-command-line-options-when-opening-a-particular-filetype/256761#256761), I made a spelling mistake.

The user was good enough to spot it and even tried to edit but couldn't.

As they will require approval anyway, is there a need to have a minimum length/changes?

Answer (score 1):

> As they will require approval anyway, is there a need to have a minimum length/changes?

This is exactly the reason for the length requirement; the theory is having no requirement will lead to sites getting flooded with single-character changes, which then need a second (and possibly third) person to review, all for a single character. I'm not convinced that would actually happen, but that's the reason for the length restriction

Comment: It already *happens*... I mean, edits that don't go far enough. I suppose it's not guaranteed that allowing shorter edits would increase the quantity of these, but it *does* give us a good opportunity to get on our soapboxes and push for more editing...

Comment: @Shog9 Lots of current edits suck, but I don't think that has anything to do with the limit

Comment: **(1)** why would a "flood" of edits or *improvements* be a bad thing? Someone who made a spelling mistake / mistake in their code will have to face it and review it, doesn't that seem fair? **(2)** As @MichaelMrozek notes, why is it assumed that there's a link between bad edits and length? (Especially in the case of code or spelling on short questions?) **(3)** I have around 500 rep on over 30 SE websites, and come across mistakes *extremely often*. As a professional proofreader, I find ridiculous not to be able to edit them... but crucial to do so, given the nb of foreign users on SE