# Response edit "characters changed" metric/limitation

Tags: bug, edits, responses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction)

It seems that Stack Overflow explicitly provides a possibility to edit responses, and even suggests "spelling" in edit comment.

Yet Stack Overflow doesn't allow edits shorter than 6 characters.

So if someone's response reads e.g. "sunchronized" or "amx value," it means I cannot correct correct that response spelling!

P.S. I understand it's yet another of these "6-non-whitespace" issues, but please fix it already!

Comment: I don't think SO suggests spelling corrections; your browser may though.

Comment: indeed a duplicate. please make stack more like wiki -- it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, SO suggests spelling corrections: "How to Edit ► fix grammatical or spelling errors ► correct minor mistakes".  But then when you try to do it, it rejects your edit.  Nice, huh?