# Will this spelling mistake ever be fixed under the current rules?

Tags: discussion, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove trivial edit restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82893/remove-trivial-edit-restriction)

More and more I've been noticing lots of spelling mistakes and grammar errors on various SE sites. There's even been several times where the answer or question has been upvoted and viewed heavily but the mistake is still there.

How could they be fixed if I can't submit trivial edits, and don't have the time/knowledge to completely rewrite the answer into something better? Do they ever get fixed, or -- since there's this anti-small-edits group -- will they always be unfixed, waiting for someone with a lot of time and a lot of knowledge to completely rewrite the answer?

Essentially I'm wondering how answers that are great (or even just good), but have spelling or grammar mistakes ever get fixed under the current rule. Do we just pretend that they are correct?

Comment: Well...you could have told us what the typo is, and someone might have fixed it...I read through the second paragraph (fast, agreed) and couldn't spot one.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby 3rd paragraph then: "Suppose that the attacker **is** some Javascript code"

Comment: @TheLQ: That's not a typo, that'd possibly be a grammar mistake but not a spelling mistake.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And? Question is still valid. Please people, **don't knitpick the hell out of the example, recommend solutions about the problem**

Comment: @TheLQ: Then my answer is all the more valid: you are wasting reviewer time by submitting small inconsequential changes that, in the larger scheme of life, do not matter. There is no factual error in that post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You can't tell me that official policy is: "Write what you want, we don't care at all about grammar and spelling"

Comment: Of course it isn't. But you cannot equate the suggested edit queue policy with post quality guidelines. Until you gain enough rep, you just cannot submit trivial edits.

Comment: If only won tiny grammatical error is left to escape, the terrorists have one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters BTW, happy? No more example. Now its a general question about policy, not a complaint about a single answer

Comment: @TheLQ: Now you are a dupe of [Remove trivial edit restriction](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82893) or similar posts I'm afraid.

Answer (score 7):

You leave such an edit to someone with experience and rep to edit it.

Suggested edits require review, and thus time from 2 people to review the change. To limit the size of the review queue only *suggested edits* have a minimal requirement of being non-trivial. High-rep users can make trivial edits at will as they can make the edit *directly* without having to go through the queue.

Comment: The question has been viewed 20,400 times and was upvoted heavily. Obviously waiting for someone with edit privileges who cares is not an acceptable solution if its not been fixed at this point.

Comment: You also have to wonder if a question got that much attention and didn't get fixed, what about all the small questions that don't get that much attention?

Comment: @TheLQ: It's one bloomin' typo, not the end of the world! :-) Obviously no one else has cared enough about it yet.

Comment: Hence this question. I care, but nobody with rep does. The entire policy was created on the idea that high rep users would edit, which in this example (and many others) shows very clearly that they don't.

Comment: @TheLQ: Have you considered the possibility that there is *no typo*? I spell-checked the first few pararagraphs and found nothing to correct.

Comment: Look at it again: "Suppose that the attacker **is** some Javascript code"

Comment: Looks perfectly grammatical to me. What would you change it to?

Comment: The sentence looks grammatical to me. Probably word usage: "is" sounds a bit weird, he probably wants it to be changed into something like "attacker uses Javascript code to attack".