# Should minor spelling errors be corrected?

Tags: discussion

I was reading through the Hottest Questions list and came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280933/why-is-the-exception-message-property-read-only). As I read it I noticed that type was misspelled as "tyep" so I figured I'd be helpful and fix it. But since I changed less than six characters, it wouldn't allow the edit. I noticed the editing guidance says to "Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits" and also to "fix grammatical or spelling errors".

My question is, are we suppose to ignore minor spelling errors?

**Edit**

Thanks to Servy's answer, I understand the situation better. Still, stackoverflow.com says

> Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see
>   questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them

and

> this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia

Neither of those imply that trying to help out with a simple edit is so complicated.

I'd thank you all for the answers and comments, but I know that's not allowed either.

Comment: There was nothing else in the entire question you could improve?

Comment: I apologise for [removing evidence](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15280933/3).

Comment: Related: [Will this spelling mistake ever be fixed under the current rules?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147363/147364#147364)

Comment: I've found if there is a spelling mistake on a post I am editing, odds are it is from a new user and there are MANY things to change.  +1 to this question for when the post is great, but the OP can't spell.

Comment: Looks like my question may be a duplicate. What's the proper thing for me to do: delete it or wait for someone to mark it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a post you should make an effort to fix *all* of the problems with that post (that you can find and are able to fix) rather than finding just one issue and fixing that, leaving lots of other work for others to do.  This is particularly true when suggesting an edit that needs to be reviewed by others.  Part of the reasoning is to recognize that the time of the reviewers is valuable, and shouldn't be spent on very minor edits as opposed to more significant edits.  Pending suggested edits also lock a post, preventing future edits to it until the suggestion is approved/denied.  When you've stopped someone from making a significant edit that fixes a lot of problem by just adding a single character to correct a typo you've caused more harm than good.

If there really isn't anything else that's wrong with this post besides this one typo, then it will need to be fixed by someone who has the privilege of editing a post without needing the edit to be reviewed (2k rep on SO for non-wiki posts).  The 6 char minimum doesn't apply to those users.  You can leave a comment for someone else to see if you would like, or if it *really* bothers you (perhaps it's a typo that causes more significant problems than the example you provided) then you could go to chat.