# Editing an SO answer with < 6 characters to correct code syntax

Tags: discussion, edits, privileges, code, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: “Edits must be at least 6 characters”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must)

This has been asked before [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters), but I think this rule should be reviewed with regard to correcting of coding syntax.

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256926/ruby-on-rails-heroku-dbmigrate-aborted/4257273#4257273) was very helpful, except that the code syntax was fatally incorrect by just one character - an extra colon has been inserted between 'rake' and 'db'.  However, removing the colon does not satisfy the 6 character rule.  I don't think the application of the rule in this case is aligned with the principle of the rule; that is, I believe removing the colon is a substantial improvement on the original answer and should be allowed in isolation.

I've re-read the answer a few times and can't see any other way I could improve it, otherwise.

Comment: The user that wrote the answer @yock was last seen 20 hours ago... have you considered writing a comment suggesting the edit to them?  I'm a bit dubious about actually changing other peoples code anyway, since it seems borderline changing the intent of the answer...

Comment: And if he doesn't come around, perhaps someone with more editing privileges will, seeing your comment.

Comment: I have the privileges to change this, but I'm not going to do so. Editing code in other people's posts (beyond *formatting* related changes) is generally off-limits to me. Leaving a comment for the person is the right approach. Let them make the change, or tell you why it shouldn't be made. Maybe they know of some trick that you don't!

Comment: Wow 5 upboats and then question closed.  I have seen a lot of questions (now I have seen one more) discussing this, with seemingly little actual community resolution.  The accepted (and highest voted) answer in the duplicate was to add an invisible HTML tag.  Really!??