# Should "Edits must be at least 6 characters" apply to edits that affect only code?

Tags: feature-request, code

Often code mistakes are only 1-3 characters but completely invalidate the code if uncorrected.

Are the reasons for this restriction in regular edits documented and well known?

Do these reasons apply to coding corrections (esp. by original author)?

Is there a reason we have this unfiltered restriction on code primary stacks like Stack Overflow?

Is this feasible to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing an SO answer with < 6 characters to correct code syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93977/editing-an-so-answer-with-6-characters-to-correct-code-syntax)

Comment: @Mark As per the FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), the opinion of the SE team is that 99.9% of the time there's something else that could use revision; they've decided to ignore the 0.1% of edge cases where there's nothing else to improve. It's also worth noting that as they require the same reviewer effort and award the same amount of rep, it's not fair to users who suggest much more substantive changes.

Comment: It's likely a duplicate but none of them came up when searching the text of the error: “Edits must be at least 6 characters” nor "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Comment: Which is alright; as this question shows up in the results now, it will serve as a signpost for users searching for that.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog While that may be true on rpg and server stacks, it's absolutely not true on coding stacks.  I have independently ran into this at least 3 times in less than 20 questions and that's after all the other corrections people have made.  Code mistakes are commonplace and regularly need tiny corrections.  I would posit this rule should be excluded for to CODE stacks specifically.  (Note: I think you were simply relaying another opinion not expressing your own so try not to take the comment as directed at you)

Comment: Maybe we could add a second line to the error... "Take this opportunity to write some documentation for the code" (none of this applies to folks with full edit rights though, meaning original authors never encounter this error)

Comment: @Shog9 I think you're on the right track but after reading the other questions I actually had a better idea: Change the error to **"Edits must be at least 6 characters for users under 2000 reputation; is there something else to improve in this post?"**  I think that would go a long way to solving this question being constantly repeated, since it sounds like it's a universal rule rather than specifically applying to someone new who may not know this opens up at higher reputation (like I did)

Comment: I like that idea

Comment: @SebastianSimon Since this is now marked as a duplicate of a "status-declined" post, do you have a suggestion about how we should post this new request (since we've changed the scope from a mechanics change to a conveyance change)?