# Suggestion: Allow 1-char edits, if they are within the code block

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags)

I wanted to fix a typo in another user's answer, and was prevented from doing it because the edit was less than 6 characters.