# Is it a good idea to either drop requirement for a limit of 6 character for edits, or drop the ability to edit for users under 2K?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I have just attempted to make my first edit of another user's post - correcting a reference to a single-letter class name, which otherwise could throw a novice (see paercebal's answer in [In C++, what is a virtual base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558/in-c-what-is-a-virtual-base-class)).

I was then confronted with the "6 letter limit" for edits because my reputation is below 2K.

Trying to understand the reason for the 6-character limit, I have found and scavenged the following threads: [Legitimate edits of less than 6 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149771/legitimate-edits-of-less-than-6-characters), [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must), [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters), [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags), and [Suggestion: Allow 1-char edits, if they are within the code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140792/suggestion-allow-1-char-edits-if-they-are-within-the-code-block).

These threads are filled with people who disagree with the rule and provide tips and tricks for workarounds.  One of these "tips and tricks" is the "accepted answer" for the third link I just gave, which is a question about how to overcome the 6-character limit.  Here is the relevant quote from the answer:

> look for other changes that can be made

It should go without saying that this is not an answer to **my** question.

Of the links above, there is only one reference to a justification (that I can find).  It says (see comment beneath second question linked above):

> The limitations imposed on low-rep editors are largely there to
>   discourage incomplete edits

Is this rationale based on experience - that (without the requirement) users below 2K would otherwise tend to overload the system with edits below 6 characters that are *trivial* or *incomplete*, such as the fixing of typos, but *otherwise* tend to make good edits (when over 6 characters), such that simply *removing* the ability for users under 2K to edit would detract from the community?

**Is it really true that for users under 2K, it is known that edits under 6 characters tend to be incomplete, but that edits over 6 characters tend to be complete?**

If so, I understand the requirement.  But in this case I would like to recommend that StackExchange add an "orange box" at the top of the "edit" page, appearing only when the editor's reputation is below 2K and only when the number of characters in the edit is less than 6, that says something like:

> Edits must be a minimum length of 6 characters for users with a
>   reputation below 2K.  This is to discourage incomplete or trivial
>   edits.  If you have a legitimate edit of less than 6 characters
>   and your reputation is below 2K, please add a comment, which will
>   be received by the post's author.

On the other hand, if the "incomplete" rationale is not justified, can StackExchange please either remove the 6-character limitation, or simply remove the ability of users under 2K to make edits?

Quite obviously, for highly popular code-oriented sites such as StackOverflow, code edits can be critical, and the length of the edit has no bearing on its legitimacy.

I suspect that the reason this issue has not been attended to is that most people who develop the StackExchange sites, and other users who make frequent edits, have reputations higher than 2,000.  In my opinion, to the extent that this is true, this is not a justification to maintain an unnecessary and/or unhelpful requirement for users whose reputation is below 2K (that is, if I'm correct that the requirement is unnecessary and/or unhelpful).

Can something please be done about this?  I have taken the time to write this post after running into this issue in order to help the StackExchange sites, so I hope someone else can follow through and recommend that something be changed.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Downvotes on Meta (per the FAQ) are often used to indicate disagreement. It might very well be that someone disagrees with your feature request. The downvote does not necessarily indicate "bad question" in this case.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140792/suggestion-allow-1-char-edits-if-they-are-within-the-code-block and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags

Comment: @BenVoigt I have carefully looked at the two links you provide, and they do not answer my question.  In particular, the second states the same answer I've highlighted: `Was the post otherwise so perfect that absolutely nothing in it could be improved?`.  The answer also contains a comment claiming that users under 2K "make trivial bit-twiddling changes".  I requested evidence for the latter, and the former rationale is not something that applies any more to those under 2K than those over.  This is a serious question I am asking.

Comment: @Dan: I am not saying that the question has been answered.  I am saying it is not a new question.  The other user asked the same question, and is unfortunately still waiting for a good answer.  Asking the question again won't somehow produce an answer that the first question didn't get.  Instead, raise awareness of the question already out there.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I thought carefully before I posted my question.  I noticed that the other questions did not provide alternatives.  In my question I made a point to provide alternatives, and to ask about these alternatives.  I did so in my title, not just the body.  Does this not count as a new question?

Comment: @Dan: I see you added those two links to your question now.  Unlike the ones you first found, they certainly did offer alternatives.  Your whole question pivots on "code edits can be critical, and the length of the edit has no bearing on its legitimacy".  This is exactly the same point made by those two earlier questions.

Comment: @BenVoigt - No.  My question provides two alternatives.  (1) Disable editing entirely for users under 2K (this is in the title of my post), and (2) provide better, dynamic text feedback in an orange box when the editor window is active (not in my title, but only for lack of space). Both of your links, and the links I originally found, offered alternatives in the answers and in the comments - but not in the questions.  Because the topic of alternatives is important - as you seem to agree - I created a new question *specifically* re. alternatives.

Comment: @BenVoigt (Also - I considered saying `"I added your links to my question"` in my comment, but it seemed irrelevant so I did not.  But since you raise the point, I will point out that I looked *very* carefully at the links you provided, came to the conclusion that they did not discuss my question directly, and therefore added them to my list of links that `"are filled with people who disagree with the rule and provide tips and tricks for workarounds"`, which is not what my question is about.)

Comment: Dan, you're unfortunately wasting your time. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128537/150034) is one of Jeff's personal idiosyncrasies, and [nothing whatsoever ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/92247#92247) will convince him to change his mind.

Answer (score 9):

My suggestion would be that the character count shouldn't be checked when any change is made inside a code snippet (either inline or block)... even a single character there can produce dramatically different results, in nearly any language.

Since <2k edits are going into a queue for review anyway, I think that's the only change needed.

In the meantime, you definitely should leave a comment on any post that contains an error if you can't fix it yourself.

Of course, this has already been proposed:

- [Suggestion: Allow 1-char edits, if they are within the code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140792/suggestion-allow-1-char-edits-if-they-are-within-the-code-block)
- [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags)

---

Please note that I'm not expressing an opinion for or against allowing low rep users to edit code... just that the number of characters changed is a useless metric of whether a change is trivial, when the change occurs in code.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed. The arbitrary limits and hard coded regulations on edits have a very annoying effect on editors wishing to help other people.

Just let people edit and let the community moderate itself like it always has.

Answer (score 2):

As you have probably seen, the 6-character limit is completely <strike>asinine</strike>arbitrary, so you should feel morally in the clear to abuse it by making pointless edits just to exceed the character limit.

One popular solution is to link to the Wikipedia page for one of the concepts in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has their excuses, but In my humble opinion, Trivial edits(formatting, spelling, grammar, etc.) are more appropriate than non-trivial edits.

Otherwise you risk changing the meaning of the post to something that the author didn't intend.

Comment: I would think that this has nothing to do with the length of the edit - if anything, it's more likely that an edit *under* 6 characters will meet your criteria and should be *allowed*, with edits *over* 6 characters disallowed.  But those are just my reflections regarding your answer.  Do you believe the 6-character limit is relevant to the issue you've raised?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum You are correct in your assumption that i disagree with the base philosophy behind the 6-character minimum limit, but you would be incorrect in your assumption that that needs to translate to an X-character **maximum** limit

Comment: Thanks - I have a slightly off-topic comment: Can something be **done** about this?

Comment: I consider the neg reps on this comment a badge of honor

Answer (score -1):

The 6-character minimum is arbitrary, just like the 30-character minimum for new answers or the 15-character minimum for comments.

They're based on the belief that, *generally-speaking*, doing something worthwhile requires a minimal amount of effort. It's pretty easy to find examples that violate this rule, and just as easy to find examples that support it. All things being equal, it rarely hurts to write *more*...

It's somewhat harder to hit [the 2K reputation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) that makes minimum edit lengths irrelevant. But *worth it*.

Comment: I don't understand how, generally speaking, it helps to *write more* when code errors are being fixed.

Answer (score -2):

I would say the system worked as it should. Code Edits are generally frowned upon for anything more than cleaning up the formatting. If you see a problem with the code, you should leave a comment so that the poster can verify and fix, or explain why it is not a problem.

**EDIT:**
[Incorrect code: Edit, comment, or provide a correct answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124111/incorrect-code-edit-comment-or-provide-a-correct-answer) I would like to point out it is a gray area and that is why I said generally.

The problem is that when you do not have enough rep to do it yourself, and it goes through the suggested edit review queue. I can tell you personally, when I see a code edit to an answer, and the answer was posted by a high rep user I tend to decline it. Rationale being that the high rep users are generally active on the site, and if the editor left a comment pointing out the problem, they would fix it or explain why their answer is correct.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference or justification for this?  It adds value to the community to fix a major code error on a software development forum.  Making such corrections can sometimes save people a great deal of time and headache, and can help prevent the spread of misinformation.  Please explain why this is not a good idea.

Comment: Re. your edit: this reasoning applies equally as well to code edits >6 characters as it does to code edits <6 characters.  My question is specifically in regards to the 6 character limit.  As noted, one of my suggestions is simply to disallow code edits for users with <2K.  Once code editing privilege is granted, I would think it means that the user is deemed to have a high enough reputation that they can be trusted.  Again, why should the 6-character limit have anything to do with the trust level - one way or the other - regarding code edits?  Your answer does not discuss this.

Answer (score -3):

When a user with less than 2k reputation suggests an edit, the idea is that they should not just be fixing one problem with the post; they should fix *all* of the problems with that post.  This limit is targeted towards what are clearly small fixes for single, narrowly scoped problems, and those are not encouraged by the system.  When someone is fixing *all* of the problems with a post it should involve editing more than 6 characters.

The reason for this is that the suggested edits need to be reviewed, and those reviews consume time and effort of multiple (2-5+) higher reputation users.  Filling the queue with lots of small edits ends up consuming much more of their time, which could be spent on more valuable edits (or other types of reviews).

Other costs with small edits are that, from the time the edit is suggested until the review is complete the post is locked.  If someone else would like to make a substantive edit but there is a very minor pending edit the substantive edit can't be made.  Additionally there is a limit of 200 pending suggested edits *for the entire site* at any one time.  If the system is flooded with lots of very minor edits the queue can end up sitting at capacity and thus preventing *anyone* from suggesting edits to *any* posts.  This is less of a problem now, with some of the changes to the review system (instead of constantly sitting near capacity during peek hours; it's usually sitting pretty low) but it's still a concern.

As for what you should do; it's fairly simple:

1. If you notice a small problem with a post that doesn't involve editing more than 6 characters, first be sure that there are no other problems with the post.  If you can find any other problems you should fix them.  Don't just change things that aren't wrong though; your edits should be correct and improvements.
2. If you still haven't edited 6 characters you can comment on that post.  Describe the small fix that needs to be made.  Either the OP, or another 2k+ user who comes along can make that edit.  If the change isn't important enough that you feel it's worthy of a comment, then clearly it's fine to leave it.  You can delete your comment if/when the change is made.
3. You can wait until you have 2k+ reputation to make such changes.  Note that even if you have 2k reputation you should still strive to fix *all* problems with a post when you edit it, but this isn't enforced nearly as much as with <2k users.

Comment: *Any* non-whitespace (and in Python, whitespace too) change to code is a substantive edit.

Comment: @BenVoigt Changing one or two characters may have a significant impact, but it can also be quite a bit more substantive to fix all of the problems with a post.  In any case, I have described what the appropriate action to take is if a single character code change is the only problem and it's a major issue.

Comment: I am not referring to **minor** edits, as you indicate, just because they are small in length.  This is not an answer to my question.  You imply that edits of less than 6 characters are *unsubstantive* (`If someone else would like to make a substantive edit but there is a very minor pending edit ...`).  I made clear in my question that I am referring to **substantive** edits of less than 6 characters.  A blatant code error of 1 character is substantive, even though it is only 1 character.  Can you please explain why substantive edits of >6 chars are more worthy of others' time than those <6?

Comment: Also, your reasoning that users who make a **critical** edit should be obligated to `"fix all of the problems with that post"` makes no sense to me.  Why should users be obligated to change **all** problems with a post, not just critical ones?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum The entirety of my post is explaining, specifically, why the general guidelines is that anytime anyone edits a post they should fix all of the problems.  Asking that makes it sound like you didn't get past the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum As for definitions of "minor" or "substantive".  A minor edit, from the point of view of this post, is one that edits only a small number of the problems in that post; a substantive one edits all, or a significant percentage, of the problems.

Comment: I do not believe you can possibly be correct.  Any reasonable system would take into consideration the **importance** of the changes, not just the **number** of changes.  In other words, an extremely important change should obviously weigh higher than an extremely trivial one.  For this reason, I request that you provide justification for your assessment that `"the general guidelines is that anytime anyone edits a post they should fix all of the problems"` with your corresponding implication that the *importance* of the issues has no bearing.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I am not the one who put the system into place. I am merely telling you what the current policy is, and how the situation ought to be handled.  If you don't want to fix all of the problems with a post then simply don't edit it; comment with the problem that you see.  While it's a side topic that's not really specific to this question, note that you should be very careful when it comes to "fixing" errors in code.  Changing the *content* of a reply isn't appropriate in an edit; only the OP should make such a change.  If the meaning of the post is changed it's an "invalid edit".

Comment: Please justify your assessment of the policy.  I don't believe it.  (And I don't believe it for the reasons in my previous comment - I strongly suspect that the *importance* of the post is a factor in both the current policy, and the current guidelines.)

Comment: Regarding your statement that `"you should be very careful when it comes to "fixing" errors in code"` - are you suspecting that I am *not* very careful?  I note that there **are** posts with legitimate code errors, and where correcting those errors provides a service.  In the link that triggered my question (see top of question), the error was obvious - an incorrect variable was referred to in later text (an easy mistake to make) - and it could save someone a big headache to just fix it.  Do you agree that it is sometimes a good idea to fix code mistakes, such as in this case?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum One of the rejection reasons in the review queue is "too minor" for which the response text is: `"This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."`.  I can't seem to find the FAQ entry on it at the moment, but what you're proposing has been brought up a number of times (you've linked to several yourself) and you said that you've commonly seen this answer given.  Asking again won't change the answer as the policy hasn't changed.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum As for code snippets, if it's clear that the OP meant to type something but got it wrong, fixing it is okay, but if the OP meant to do something and you think that it's wrong then changing it in an edit would be inappropriate.  In this case, it does appear that the OP didn't enter what they meant, so editing it would be fine.

Comment: Do you honestly believe that if an edit is **extremely** important, but only addresses one issue, that the edit should be rejected on the basis that only one issue is addressed?  It seems to me that you are being nit-picky.  I am addressing the guidelines and the established culture; again, please provide evidence that the culture and guidelines support outright rejection of **important** edits on the basis that only one issue is addressed (rather than multiple issues).  You mention that you cannot find the FAQ's.  Are you suggesting that you believe the FAQ's will make such a statement?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Yes, I am saying that if you fix just one small issue in a post in a suggested edit and leave many other glaring errors unaddressed the edit should be rejected given the "too minor" reason, which has the text that I described.  That is the established policy, given that the rejection reason exists; but I can only find it reference from the point of view of the reviewer, not directed at the person suggesting the edit.

Comment: I agree, also, that making the edit in the post that triggered this question would be fine.  I was not allowed to make that edit *on the basis that it was less than 6 characters*.  Do you agree that I should not have been able to make this edit on that basis alone?  My question seeks to improve the StackExchange sites (or, at least, the code-oriented SE sites) by providing meaningful alternatives to what many other questions (including their answers and comments) clearly indicate is a problem - as you seem, also, to agree.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Can you see any other errors in the post?  If you can, you should make those as well in your suggested edit?  If not, my post describes the appropriate course of action for a user without enough reputation to make the edit, and that is to leave a comment.  For a post that old, if the OP isn't active (and therefore not likely to change it) you could also go to chat to find an active user with enough rep to make the change; that would be appropriate if you felt the problem was important.  I have already explained why such small edits shouldn't be proposed directly.

Comment: I did not suggest that edits should be accepted that leave `"other glaring errors unaddressed"`.  I am, and have been, responding to you on the issue you raised re. posts for which there is, *specifically*, only one glaring error.  Therefore, in regards to the scenario of one error, I ask again: `"Do you honestly believe that if an edit is extremely important, but only addresses one issue, that the edit should be rejected on the basis that only one issue is addressed?"` (and with the added clarification that the issue addressed in the edit is assumed to be the *only* important issue in need).

Comment: You have simply not explained why small edits should not be proposed directly in terms of its relationship to the 6-character limit - your only explanation is that multiple errors need to be fixed, not just one error.  But, as I said, that reasoning does *not* address the distinction between <6 characters and >6 characters, and so is irrelevant to the question I asked.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum If there is only one edit that you can think to make, and it is less than 6 characters, it can't be suggested, and so isn't up for rejection in the queue.  If there is only one error to be fixed, and fixing it takes more than 6 characters, and so it's in the queue, then I would accept the edit if there were no other problems with the post.  The reason for the restriction is that the number of posts with only one error that can be fixed in just 5 characters is *very* small.  The queue was clogged with lots of small edits like changing `i` to `I` (just once) and so this was added.

Comment: Am I to understand that you agree that **`"for users under 2K, it is known that edits under 6 characters tend to be minor, but that edits over 6 characters tend to be important?"`** (to paraphrase the sentence in bold in my question).  If so, I understand and agree with the 6-character requirement.  However, I would like to know if you have this understanding from *experience* / *knowledge*, or because it's a logical possibility (but you don't know if it's true)?  If this *is* true, then I provided an alternative: an orange informational text box.  Do you agree that this would be a good idea?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum That statement is not true.  Edits under 6 characters are so likely to be too minor that they are automatically rejected, due to the very low changes that they're acceptable.  For those exceptional cases where this catch is a "false positive" the appropriate solution is to have a user with >2k rep, or the OP, make the change.  This is one of those exceptional cases.  While it caused a problem for you this once, in the general case it helps much than it hurts.  Also note that just because someone edited >6 chars doesn't make it a good edit; it can still be too minor.

Comment: To summarize your justification of the requirement: `"Edits under 6 characters have a high likelihood of being minor, so to avoid swamping the system, users with <2K rep are not allowed to propose any changes of less than 6 characters, even though it is known that some important changes (such as for source code) will go uncorrected with this restriction in place"`.  If so, then my question remains: Would it be a good idea simply to prohibit users <2K from proposing **any** changes - or else provide useful informational text in an orange box for those <2K, as I suggested?  I would think so.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum The last statement is incorrect.  Just because <2k users can't propose them doesn't mean they can't go uncorrected; they simply need to be corrected by a user with more than 2k reputation.  Also keep in mind that *lots* of people like making very minor edits, and *very* few of them are substantial.  As to prohibiting all changes.  I think that there are *lots* of edits that can be made that are more than 6 characters.  The vast, vast majority of edits that should be make will change more than 6 characters.  I don't see why all of those valid edits should be prohibited.

Comment: Why do you believe that just because you couldn't make this one edit that you feel is right that no other <2k users should ever be able to suggest any edits? Do you have evidence to suggest that the vast majority of proposed edits are bad, such that the effort spend to have the review process is worse than the benefits of having the content edited?  I would disagree with such an assertion.

Comment: I do *not* believe that users under 2K should be prohibited from proposing edits.  You are the one who is justifying that users under 2K be prohibited from proposing edits (if <6 chars).  Your statement is that legitimate changes <6 chars are **so rare** that it is acceptable to prohibit users <2K from proposing such changes, even though some *legitimate* changes will be prohibited from being proposed with this restriction in place - but that changes >6 chars are more **likely** to provide value, so users <2K *should* be allowed to propose these. What about my `orange box` alternative, then?

Comment: I do not believe it is a serious argument to say that errors `"simply need to be corrected by a user with more than 2k reputation"`.  If a user with <2K reputation cannot even *propose* such a correction, than it could easily be months, or years, before another user discovers the mistake with sufficient confidence to make the change.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum If they do nothing, maybe, if they do one of the things that I've proposed that simply don't involve suggesting the edit themselves, then that's unlikely.  All they need to do is comment, go to chat, etc.  If it's really that big of a change, someone will help you change it.  As I've said; this is an *extreme* edge case, and you're making it sound like the end of the world.  It's not.

Comment: Please provide justification that this is an *extreme* edge case.  Your arguments here come down to this: *"valid changes that are <6 chars are such an **extreme edge case** that it is not worth dealing with them properly, given the other advantages to prohibiting edits that are <6 chars"*. First, I question your assessment that they are an *extreme edge case*; second, I question your assessment that users <2K are more likely to provide legit. edits >6 chars; and third, I proposed an `'orange box'` wording alternative that handles ALL scenarios, and you have not responded to this suggestion.

Comment: `"I question your assessment that users <2K are more likely to provide legit. edits >6 chars"` I'm not saying that all >6k edits are good.  In fact, I've found that when reviewing edits I have about a 50% rejection rate; meaning 50% of the edits that I see I feel should be rejected, not accepted.  None of those are <6 char edits.  So the quality of existing reviews is rather low.  Now, if <6 char edits were allowed I'm sure we'd see that percentage go down further still.  As for my reasoning for this; I edit a lot of posts myself.  I very rarely need to make <6 char edits.

Comment: As for your suggested text addition; I just don't see enormous value in it.  I don't think I'd go so far as to say it's a bad idea, merely that, as I've said, this is such an edge case, it isn't needed.  The value added is very low.  It's certainly better than your proposal of elimination all edit suggestions though.

Comment: I do not believe that you have a good justification that edits <6 chars are more likely to be illegitimate for users <2K.  Just as you very rarely make edits that are <6 chars, just so it may be that users <2K are also much less likely to make such edits, but that when they do, the fraction of bad ones may be the same.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Your arguments are based on your theories of using the system.  Mine is based on a significant amount of past experience both in making edits, seeing what edits other users tend to make, seeing the edits that others tend to suggest, and also the actions other reviews tend to take as reviewers.  I'm not saying that I don't think this is likely to come up should such a restriction be added; I'm saying that this restriction has existing for a long time and it very rarely comes up.  Almost every time I see someone even mention this rule it's because they want to make a minor edit.

Comment: Servy, your rhetoric is not solid.  It is not good commentary to take someone's comments clearly out of context.  Anyone reading my question, and my comments, would understand that I feel that the restriction on <6 chars should be removed, rather than that users <2K should be prohibited from proposing any edits.  I provide the alternatives to raise the issue in a way that the other linked questions have not succeeded in doing.  This comment (as well as another) sounds like nit-pickyness.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum So you propose a completely horrible suggestion to a commonly raised problem merely so that it won't be a duplicate, but in fact what you really want to propose is an exact duplicate of something that has been suggested many times.  In that case, I refer you to all of the exact duplicates of your "true" proposal.  The topic is widely discussed.

Comment: I understand that you feel, based on your experience, that the ratio of poor edits made by users <2K would likely increase if users <2K were allowed to propose edits <6 chars; and that the occurrence of legitimate code errors that require changes <6 chars is such an *extreme edge case* that it does not outweigh the former concern.  You add that my suggestion of an orange box isn't worth the time/energy, because it is such an extreme edge case.  If your point of view reflects the community at large; fine.  I suspect that I will continue to disagree as I gain more experience, but perhaps not.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I said that adding a box is likely to add very little value to the site.  That's partially because there are very few appropriate cases of <6 char edits, but also because people just don't read boxes like that; they tend to just gloss over them.  If it won't be read even when it is applicable then it's still not helpful.  In any case, I wouldn't oppose it's addition, I simply wouldn't endorse it.  Your other suggestions I would strongly oppose though.

Comment: Servy - No.  I ask if it is a good idea to completely restrict users <2K, rather than restrict them under 6 characters, because I think that *others* might (legitimately) feel that way (even though I do not feel that way).  I you agree that the <2K restriction is a completely horrible idea, that answers that part of the question.  The other questions linked did not ask this question.  Indeed, I'd like to know the answer.  That is why I asked.  I also provided the `"orange box"` alternative, which I do support if the <6 char restriction won't or can't be removed.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Wait, so you really were serious about your suggestion to completely remove suggested edits, and you were just messing with me when I criticized that suggestion?  Now I'm all confused.  Maybe you should figure out what you want to propose before criticizing the answers to your proposal.

Comment: I don't agree that people "gloss over" the orange boxes.  If that's your reason for not endorsing my idea, I ask you to reconsider.

Comment: Servy - Your rhetoric is not sound.  You have repeatedly taken my comments entirely out of context, and it's not helpful.  As I said, I proposed that suggestion because I feel that others might agree with it, so I wanted to put it on the table.  I myself do not agree with it, but feel it is important to ask.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I belive that a fairly small percentage of users read them. It's some, sure, but not an overwhelming percentage.  It's merely another factor that contributes to the lack of value of this suggestion.  Again, it wouldn't be *bad*, per say, and I wouldn't oppose it, I just don't see it helping enough to be worth the time and effort (which is non-trivial) of implementing it.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum What have I taken out of context, and what is the proper context for it?  I can say for sure that you've taken my comments out of context, and I've corrected you on the several occasions where you've tried to paraphrase me incorrectly.

Comment: Servy - I dispute your assessment that only a "fairly small percentage of users read" the orange boxes.  StackOverflow, in particular, has a well designed user experience that draws attention to the orange boxes effectively, in my opinion.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Well perhaps you should pay attention to the dozens of daily meta posts referring to information that plastered right in front of their face, such as the "why can't I ask questions anymore" threads who clearly haven't even read the message displayed when they try to ask a question.

Comment: Servy - this isn't a useful discussion any more.  I feel I have been clear in my comments, and I feel I was clear in my question.  If you feel the same about your comments, excellent.  I made it explicitly clear what I felt you have taken out of context, and the reason for my sense of this.  You gave no specifics when you stated that I have taken your comments out of context, so I can't assess how this relates to my posted question or our relevant commentary.  If you have something to add that clarifies this, feel free to do so.  Otherwise, I don't think this conversation is worth continuing.

Comment: You seem to be lumping all users into the category of those that do not read the orange boxes.  Along the same lines, that would be reason to remove all orange boxes - would it not?  This does not bear on whether my orange box suggestion is a good one.

Comment: `"all users"` No, I merely indicated that many wouldn't, thus reducing their value.  As for removing all of them, I never indicated that would be a good idea.  Take that as one example of taking my comments out of context.  I feel that your suggestion adds very little.  It's not bad. The world won't end if it's implemented, but there the instances in which it would be useful are so contrived, and the consequences of not having are so low, that it's just not worth the cost of implementing, which is not low.  You're really overcomplicating the issue and exaggerating the negative consequences.

Comment: I think we have a different assessment of what it means to take something out of context. The real underlying issue, I think, is that you feel the scenario of valid edits <6 chars for users <2K is so *`"extremely rare"`* that it's pretty much a waste of time considering changes to handle it. I disagree. (You also show a bit of disdain towards some users.) But, you have more experience. If you're correct, and if the community feels the same, fine- that's the answer. I do not have confidence in your comments, however, because I haven't found them particularly convincing, despite your experience.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum  I can tell you that On multiple occasions before I reached 2k, I would find questions where code blocks weren't formatted as code blocks.  When the asker posts that it looks horrible.  Sometimes multiple lines of code merge into the same line.  indenting blocks of code is just adding more spaces, but the 6-character limit doesn't count white-space, so if you want to just indent a block of code, you'll find yourself having to invent other reasons why the post needs to be edited further