# How can I get a notification when someone else's question is reopened?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, vote-to-reopen, follow-post

Does a feature like this exist? A question has been closed, because the user must write it in a better way.

I have already an answer for it, and it would be great to have an alert/notification when it will be open again.

Comment: I'd recommend not to tag a question [tag:feature-request] unless you have a [fully fleged one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request).

Comment: You can just follow the question and you will be notified of any activity on it.

Comment: no @MarkKirby , it seems that only the author will get a notification when a question is open again

Comment: @MarkKirby I have read it there https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351105/460253

Comment: It should be relatively easy to add reopen actions as a notification for following. Since I can certainly imagine that someone might follow a closed question to see if it gets reopened - so that they can answer it - I think this seems like a reasonable addition to the current feature. I'll see if we can make this happen. :)

Comment: You can always use a web tracker like [pageprobe](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pageprobe/) for firefox. Just select the word closed over your question and select "Track Content".

Comment: @Des is there any timeline more precise then 6-8 weeks for this?

Comment: @Luuklag not at the moment but we are queueing it up for review on our next grooming call. I can drop a comment here when it gets pulled into an active sprint if that's helpful. Should be within the next couple of sprints.

Comment: Thanks @Des. Sounds like its more on the 6 side then the 8 side, so thats good to know. Well see when this gets status-completed. That's soon enough for me.

Comment: I was really surprised to see that a closed question that I had followed was reopened weeks ago. I followed it so that I could answer it when reopened. This is literally the most obvious use of a "follow" feature. Stunned it doesn't work as I expected it to.

Comment: @Des any news about this feature? Thank you

Comment: @Des: anything new about this? [I just posted the same feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355156/256777) and got sent here almost before I clicked "post"...

Comment: @StephanKolassa: It's tagged "status-planned", which means they plan to implement it when they get to it. Could be 4-6 weeks, could be 4-6 years...

Comment: @StephanKolassa no update. The tickets are groomed and in our backlog but are secondary in priority compared to some other active projects. Still planned though and ready to be picked up as soon as time permits.

Comment: @SonictheK-DayHedgehog you are right but this is an important feature and should be implemented soon :(

Comment: Actually, looking at the extended tag wiki, it seems the current tag is OK.

Answer (score 7):

A [similar post on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397829/notify-me-when-a-question-that-i-follow-gets-reopened) made the same request, and the functionality was added in October. See the linked post for details.