# Notify post followers of reopening

Tags: feature-request, reopened-questions, follow-post

If I am following a closed question, can I please be notified when it is reopened?

Concrete example: [Elasticity of negative binomial regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/490417/1352) on CrossValidated. It was originally closed as unclear, but the OP clarified, so I voted to reopen and followed the question, intending to write an answer when it was reopened. However, it turns out that it was reopened, but although I was following it, I did not get a notification. (The OP posted a comment alerting me to the reopening.)

I think this kind of use case may be pretty common.

Note that [the original poster is notified of reopenings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336960/256777).