# Option to format and view C and C++ code with ClangFormat

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

I want an option to render blocks of code found in questions and answers, with [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html), so I can read the C++ and C code in the style I deem appropriate.

Comment: Jannies, is this a duplicate?: [C is not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354753/282094) by highlighting.

Comment: @Rob Definitely no. Clang-format would allow you to view code how you are used to viewing it. Has little to do with syntax highlighting.

Comment: The reasoning for this feature request is basically none because what you deem appropriate is not what we deem appropriate (please read [How do I write a good feature request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258136/241919)). Also, just FYI, all of us here are just users who don't have the privilege to modify the source code of this site. Only limited SE devs can implement it.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. the `We` can be pretty cliquey. Oh well; they do it for free. Kind of amazing when you think of it. Thanks for advice ill read it.

Answer (score 7):

1. Copy the code in the post
2. Paste it in your favorite IDE
3. Format the code according to your personal settings
4. Profit!

No need to bother the Stack Exchange developers with this, if you ask me ...

Comment: Doing that would take like half an hour. This could be programmed in less time than that.

Comment: It'd take me five seconds to follow those steps. Why 1) do you think it takes so long 2) do you expect the devs can do it much faster?

Comment: 5 seconds? You are clearly inexperienced if you believe that you are going to edit the html code and have it display clang-formatted code from your ide, with syntax highlighting and everything, in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: You don't need to edit the HTML code at all. I don't have experience with clang itself, but I'm pretty sure the main IDEs have plugins for it. (If you're using Notepad to code, you're out of luck...) And even if they wouldn't, *why do you expect the developers can implement it as a site feature in less time than it would take you to do it for a single case*?

Comment: How do you get SO to display your clang-formatted code without editing the HTML? And if you know what you are doing, it could be done in 30 minutes. Its really that easy.