# Should we improve/filter hot question?

Tags: feature-request, questions, hot-questions

> We see migrated, close, down voted (more than five down voted)
> questions are in hot tab.

***From this scenario many questions arise in mind  & See the picture below***

These types of questions are hot question?

What is the definition of hot questions? (It does not mean  how algorithm work .. It means how people think about  hot question )

When question are closed for `off topic` , `Details or Clarity` or etc.…

Should we remove those type of questions from hot, week, month tab?

**Feature Request**

I would like to request to remove those type of questions from hot, week, month tab

**Picture**

[image]

Comment: And discussion. It can't be both. Also I see no feature being requested in your question, only discussion.

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request

Comment: ... and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192046/in-network-hot-questions-formula-discard-answers-when-voting-evidence-indicat?rq=1