# CMake Syntax Highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I see that [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) supports cmake, but [highlight-loader.js](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/highlightjs-loader.en.js) currently doesn't make use of it.

I'm attempting to follow the directions given here:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/159385

Comment: please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request